# authenticate private vcs with specific user

Tags: php, git, ssh, composer-php, gitblit

I'm using gitblit to self-host my git repositories.
I added them to my composer file:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "ssh://user@my.gitblit.com:29418/foo/repo.git"
    }
]
```

It works well except I'm asked for the password for every of those repos.
I wonder how I authenticate. I see that I can enter username, password but not for git.
I see that I can authenticate with keys but the user running the install/update command is `www-data` and not `user` who has rights to read the repositories.

How do I authenticate to this so I can run composer unattended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell composer what key to use for each repository.

From [the doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#security) :

```
{
  "repositories": [{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "ssh2.sftp://example.org",
    "options": {
      "ssh2": {
        "username": "composer",
        "pubkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
        "privkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Where would I get that key? I saw nothing on gitblits interface.

Comment: you have to generate a ssh key and add it to your authorized keys into gitblit. see here for more information : http://gitblit.com/setup_transport_ssh.html

Comment: it doesn't work. if I add that and run composer update it asks for the password of `www-data`

Comment: additionally `user` does only exists in gitblit not on the server, I guess that is another problem.